# Merge a table and a shapefile in FME

Tags: shapefile, fme-form

I am testing the trial version of FME 2014 in order to make sure I can build some workflows on it. If its possible then we plan to proceed with buying a license.

Right now I have build a workflow which partially works. I have some questions on how to accomplish something and I was wondering if you can help me with.

Right now my workflow is separated into two workspaces. The first one takes an Excel (applies some attribute filter) and imports everything in a database in postgresql (with sql executor). This workflow doesn't include any spatial data.

The second one takes a dwg file, applies some transformations and it outputs a shapefile with point geometry plus some other attributes (id etc.).

Now, the table from the first procedure and the shapefile from the second procedure have in common this id.

What I want to do is to complete this workflow by merging them into a big table in PostgreSQL (with PostGIS extension). The crucial part here is that I want this table to get updated later with more values (inserting more values).

What is the procedure I have to use?

Right now I have tried to use SQL Executor in order to pass the data from the ShapeFile into the same database but it doesn't work cause there is geometry user attribute available to choose. Why does this happen?

Comment: FeatureMerger is what we use http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FME_Transformers.htm#Transformers/featuremerger.htm with UPDATE on the PostGIS writer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this page will answer your question: http://blog.safe.com/2011/05/fmeevangelist79/

It sounds like using the 'Joiner' transformer in your workflow will work. The crucial part you mention makes it sound like you don't actually want to merge the two, but rather add a relationship between the table and the shapefile.